# $f,g \in [0,1] , f<g $ , when is $U:=\{h \in C[0,1]:f(t)<h(t)<g(t), \forall t \in [0,1] \}$ a ball in $C[0,1]$ with respect to the sup metric

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $f,g:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be continuous functions such that $f(t)<g(t),\forall t \in [0,1]$ , then under what

additional conditions on $f,g$ can we conclude that

$U:=\{h \in C[0,1]:f(t)<h(t)<g(t), \forall  t \in [0,1] \}$ is a ball in $C[0,1]$ with respect to the sup metric

$d(f,g):=\sup_{t\in [0,1] }|f(t)-g(t)| $ ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let's have a look on what is the shape of a ball in $C[0,1]$.

If $F \in C[0,1]$ and $r >0$, then the ball with center $F$ and radius $r$ is
$$B_r(F) = \{ h \in C[0,1] : F(t)-r < h(t) < F(t)+r, \forall t \in [0,1]\}$$

You can see that this is very similar to the definition of $U$.

Now you can easily show that a necessary and sufficient condition for $U$ to be  a ball is that $g-f = 2r$ is a constant function. In this case $U$ will be the ball of radius $r =\frac{1}{2} (g-f)$, and center $f+r$ (which is equal to $g-r$).

Answer (score 0):

$U$ becomes a ball iff there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $g = f +2\epsilon$. Let $U = B(x,r)$. If $f < h -\epsilon$ then there exists $t$ such that $f(t) < h(t) -\epsilon$ and then if we take $\delta = \frac{h(t) -\epsilon -f(t)}{2} > 0$ ut $f+ \delta \in U $ but not in $B(x,r)$. And similarly we can do the other cases.