# Ex. 1.2.56 - Topology of metric spaces by Kumaresan

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let be $X := \mathcal{C}[0,1]$ withe the $\sup$ norm metric $|| \ \ ||_{\infty}$. Let $E$ be the set of all functions in $X$ that do not vanish (that is, they do not take the value $0$) at $t = 0$. Is $E$ open in $X$?

I think that $E$ is open in $X$. Next, my attempt:

> Define $A_f := \{ |f(t)| \in \mathbb{R} \ ; \ f(t) \neq 0 \}$ and $R_f := \inf A_f$ (clearly, $R_f$ > 0). If $f \in E$, then exists $R_f > 0$ such that $B(f,R_f) \subset E$. Indeed, given $g \in B(f,R_f)$, i.e., $\sup_{t \in [0,1]} | g(t) - f(t) | < R_f$, then $|g(t) - f(t)| < \inf A_f$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, i.e., $f(t) - \inf A_f < g(t) < f(t) + \inf A_f$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, in particular, $f(0) - \inf A_f < g(0) < f(0) + \inf A_f$. Now, we analyze two cases:
>
> Case 1 - f(0) > 0:
>
> In this case, we have $f(0) + \inf A_f > 0$ and $f(0) - \inf A_f \geq 0$, then $0 \leq f(0) - \inf A_f < g(0) < f(0) + \inf A_f$ and we have $g \in E$ because $g(0) > 0$
>
> Case 2 - f (0) < 0:
>
> In this case, we have $f(0) - \inf A_f < 0$ and $f(0) + \inf A_f$ $\textbf{???}$

but now I getting stuck from $\textbf{???}$. Is it true that $E$ is open in $X$? I would like to receive a hint how to prove that $E$ is open in case 2 or a counter example that show that $E$ is not open in $X$.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I think it's not true that $E$ is open because $f(t) - \inf A_f < g(t) < f(t) + \inf A_f$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ is an particular case of this question:

[Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156093/f-g-in-0-1-fg-when-is-u-h-in-c0-1fthtgt-forall-t-i?rq=1)

then is not true that $E$ is open in $X$ in general.

Comment: Why don't you try to prove $E^c$ is closed, it's much easier

Comment: @George I know its been quite a while, but I was going through your proof, and In case 2, $f(0) <0$, so $|f(0)| = -f(0)$. And, $inf A_{f} < |f(0)|$ which means $f(0) + inf A_{f} < 0$, thus $g(0) < 0$, and hence $ g \in E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi : X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi(f) = f(0)$, clearly the mapping is well defined.

Claim: $f_n \to f$ in $C[0,1] \implies f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$

Now for any $f_n \to f $ in $C[0,1]$ we have for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|f_n - f\|_{\infty}<\epsilon$ for $n \geq n_0$

i.e $\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f_n(x) - f(x)|< \epsilon$ for $n\geq n_0$ and since $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. We see that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0$ and for all $x\in [0,1]$.

So $f_n  \to f$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$, this implies $f_n \to f$ converges pointwise on $[0,1]$, in particular $f_n(0) \to f(0)$.

Now for any $f_n \to f$ in $C[0,1] \implies f_n(0) \to f(0)$ so $\phi(f_n) = f_n(0) \to f(0) = \phi(f)$ i.e $\phi$ is continuous on $C[0,1]$.So its inverse image of an open set is open. Therefore $E = \phi^{-1}\{(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)\}$ is open.